# Creating a branch in expect, using an IF statement

Tags: bash, expect

I am writing an `expect` script to deal with a plethora of prompts.

The `bash` script that I am working with can follow one of two sequences:

1. `prompt1 -> prompt2 -> prompt3`
2. `prompt1 -> prompt3`

That is, sometimes I don't get `prompt2`. Therefore, my question is: how do I write an `expect` script which checks for `prompt2`, and if it is there sends a `y` and proceeds further, else it just proceeds.

EDIT:
Thanks to @glenn for the input, and for the answer! I shall try and make the question clearer, just in case it would help someone else in the future. The particular `bash` script I am dealing with is to download some data from a server. So usually, what happens when I execute the script is:

```
Do you want to download data from *server name*?
y
Do you want to download data from *some directory within server*?
y
...
```

Sometimes, however, I have not connected to the server when I execute this script. So I have included a part in the script which checks if I have connected to the server. If I haven't, it gives me another prompt, like so:

```
Do you want to download data from *server name*?
y
Looks like you are not connected to *server name*! Want to connect now?
y
Do you want to download data from *some directory within server*?
y
...
```

Comment: I don't understand. Please post an annotated screenshot of an interactive session

Comment: `read -p 'prompt1: '; ((RANDOM % 2)) && read -p 'prompt2: '; read -p 'prompt3: '`, @glennjackman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is what you want: an `expect` command that waits for *either* "prompt2" *or* "prompt3"

```
expect "prompt1"
send "answer to prompt1\n"
expect {
    "prompt2" {send "y\n"; exp_continue}
    "prompt3"
}
send "answer to prompt3\r"
```

`exp_continue` is basically a loop: remain inside this expect command and continue to look for the listed patterns.

"prompt3" has no corresponding action, so the expect command ends.